# Beamer – Slides with no subsections and \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I have a problem with the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{boxes}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Structure}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Structure}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}


\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My problem is that, when we start the section immediately after the "structure" slide, there is more space between the items. Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time.

Comment: Please make a compilable minimal working example which allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Updated (incidentally, it also made me realize that the problem is partly with the code right before the title).

Comment: You can use `\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections]` to get the same spacing in your structure slides as in the outline

Comment: Thanks a lot. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections]` to get the same spacing in your structure slides as in the outline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{boxes}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Structure}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideallsubsections]
  \end{frame}
}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}


\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\section{Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```